# Restrict end date before start date MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am busy making a calendar of sort for personal use, and I wonder if I can restrict the value for the start date to be before the end date(or other way around) by adding a restriction on the table fields themselfs.

I would like to do this while creating the table.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not implement check constraints.  So, in order to do what you are asking, you would need to implement a trigger.

But, there may be another way, just by revising the problem.  Instead of storing the end date, store the number of days -- as an unsigned value.  Then, you always know that the end date is on or after the start date.

You can then create a view to calculate the actual end date:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*, date_add(start_date, interval dur day) as end_date
    from t;
```

Comment: I see, and what if I were to also add a start and end time?

Comment: @Jelmergu . . . If you have another question, you should ask it as a question, not in a comment.